# Encoding of an EXE program

Tags: windows, encoding, utf-8

I haven't found any answer or clarification on this subject in the internet.

I have a very old program (over a decade old) for windows (portable executable exe). It displays data in my language (hebrew) and uses cp1255 encoding (old, today is obsolete due to UTF-8). now, the thing is - it only displays data on specific types of computers, so long I've only been able to run it on:

x32 bit windows 7

My question is whether I can get it to work on x64 bit windows 7 encoding. On the x64, the program actually launches, but it displays a whole lot of question marks and jibrish instead of hebrew. I conclude this is due to the encoding.

Sidenote: The program loads info to display from unidentified files (their extensions are fabricated and I have tried to recover and types but so long not very successful). They too, have data in hebrew using the old CP1255 encoding and also has some machine code in it (opened it with a notepad, weird symbols along with text)

I've come up with 2 possible solutions for now:

Either somehow make the program support UTF-8, translate the exe to UTF-8 (probably requires special programs or reverse engineering)

OR

make my OS support the old encoding (cp1255 / windows-1255)

I haven't been able to execute either of them.

If you have any more solutions to tackle this problem or know how to solve it with one of the possible solutions, I'd be glad!

-yuval.

Edit: By the way - I have the language installed. I am using hebrew as one of the keyboard languages and I surf the web with it.

Comment: More info:
1. I've tried recovering the data files' types using trID, I've been able to associate it with DiskDupe 5.12 Image file and Sybase iAnywhere database file.
2. The data files are seperated to 3 different types, X Y and Z. all of their names are written in Hebrew. The file names are not jibrish when transfered to the x64 computer - but their contents are (when text is supposed to be hebrew).

Comment: I have hebrew installed.

Answer (score 0):

You may have already gone down this path, but have you given a try to running in compatibility mode on your x64 machine? Right click on the executable or shortcut, open properties, and go to the compatibility tab. There is a troubleshooter there that could help.

Comment: I have, same results. Thanks anyway though!